# CQRS How to avoid repeating fields between command and event?

Tags: java, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm implementing a project using CQRS and Event Sourcing. I realized that my commands and my events are nearly always the same.

Let's say I have a command `CreatePost` :

```
public class CreatePost implements Command {
    private final String title;
    private final String content;
}
```

The event fired from this command is the same :

```
public class PostCreated implements Event {
    private final String title;
    private final String content;
}
```

How do you handle that in your applications ?

**EDIT** : Of course I'm aware of basic OOP technics. I could create an abstraction having the common fields, but this question needs to be taken in the CQRS/ES context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to avoid repeating fields between command and event?

I wouldn't -- not until I absolutely can't stand it.

Fundamentally, commands and events [aren't objects](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AttheBoundaries,ApplicationsareNotObject-Oriented/), they are messages - representations of state that cross boundaries.  I think it's important that your in memory representation not lose sight of that.

One of the characteristics of message schemas is that they evolve over time, so you need to be aware of [compatibility](https://leanpub.com/esversioning).  And here's the kicker: events and commands evolve on different time scales.

Command messages are how your domain model communicates with other processes; changes to that part of the API are driven by exposing/deprecating functionality.

But in an event sourced world, events are messages from previous versions of the domain to the current version.  They are part of the support we need to deploy new models that resume work from where the old model left off.

So I would keep commands and events separate from one another - they are different things.

If you are seeing a lot of duplication in the fields, that may be a hint that there's some value type that you haven't yet made explicit.

```
CreatePost 
    { Post 
        { Title
        , Contents
        }
    }

PostCreated
    { Post 
        { Title
        , Contents
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply implement a model for your `Post`, i.e.:

```
public class PostModel {
    private String title;
    private String content;

    // Add get/set methods
}
```

Then re-use this in both your events and commands.

Comment: How so? Because they happen to just reference a shared class?

Comment: Exactly. What if the command would need an additionat property? All the events are going to get it as well, which is simply a no-go for me, since events should be as tight as possible, carrying only the needed information.

Comment: @kayess is it an option to have a `PostModelBase`, and a `PostEventModel` and `PostCommandModel` that derive from it?

Comment: It certainly is. But also recommending inheritance in such an idea is also bad, and would probably just lead to more unneeded complexity. Why not just create an interface for those and implement it?

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm a .NET developer and I know just a bit of CQRS theory, but this seems like a plain old OOP design problem to me. If it's not to you then I guess you'll just have to accept duplication (as it is acceptible in some scenarios other than CQRS too), search for a (likely convoluted) framework, start building a framework, or switch programming languages...

Comment: @kayess an interface seems fine to me, and indeed even a better suggestion than inheritance, but you will still have duplicate *implementations* of those fields and their getters/setters. That's where I like .NET much more with its auto-properties.

Comment: Yep Mario. Me too thinks that an interface is better, the duplications _might_ not neccessarily be bad, since these are valid per bounded context/module/whatever. Anyway I would skip inheritance (since there is no behaviour), and would just aim for having a well defined contract.

Comment: Yep I want to avoid inheritance as much as possible. So to be clear, you guys recommand creating `IPost` and make the command and the event implement it ?

Comment: Personally I would go for `IPost` and `IEvent`. Naming is hard... choose wisely as your business or technical language dictates. I would split them because: even if property names are the same, they mean and indicate different things. A command is something that actually happens (and _may_ contain more information than needed for an event), whereas an event is about something (the outcome) that already happened.

Answer (score 1):

Just compiling this answer from the discussion we had in comments.

#### [Compose, don't inherit](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose)

I would definitely not use inheritance in a situation like this because it will just add unnecessary complexity, also there is no behavior to inherit there.

Another option is to have a well-defined contract for your commands and events. That is to have two interfaces — `IPost` and `IEvent` — and implement those in the commands and events.

Regarding naming: we all know that [naming is hard](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html), so you should choose names wisely, according to your business or technical language/vocabulary requirements.

#### Why split into two interfaces?

Because a command usually carries more information required for its handler than an event carries for its event handler, event handlers should be kept as thin as possible. It's better to carry only the needed payload.

#### Closing words

Separating commands and events is a must, since commands are representing an operation that's happening *now*, whereas events are representing actions that happened in the *past*. They might usually be an outcome of a command, indicating to the outside world — from the viewpoint of a bounded context — that something happened inside your current BC.

Answer (score 1):

> How to avoid repeating fields between command and event?

Just don't. The cost of dependency + risk of wrongful mutualization are higher than the maintenance gain. You can live with that duplication, just like you probably live with duplication between your domain model, view model, query model, etc. today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you want *as long as it is just an implementation detail*.

In `PHP` I use a lot `traits` for this kind of reusability. You can use even inheritance but the clients (the code that uses those classes) should not depend on the base class; it would be best if they even don't find out that your event and command class share something but I don't have enough Java experience to tell you how to do it.

P.S. I would not go with creating interfaces, as I specified above, this should be just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this, and almost universally I've not found a case where the event needed different properties than the command for a particular domain action. I definitely find the menial copy/paste duplication of property getters/equals/hashCode/toString pretty annoying. If I could go back, I'd define a marker `interface Action` and then

```
interface Command<T extends Action> {
  T getAction();
  // other properties common to commands of all action types...
}

class AbstractCommand<T extends Action> implements Command<T> {
  public T getAction() { ... }
  // other properties...
}

interface Event<T extends Action> {
  T getAction();
  // other properties common to events of all action types...
}

class AbstractEvent<T extends Action> implements Event<T> {
  public T getAction() { ... }
  // other properties...
}
```

Then for each domain action, define concrete implementations.

```
class ConcreteAction implements Action {
  // properties COMMON to the command and event(s)...
}

class ConcreteCommand extends AbstractCommand<ConcreteAction> { ... }

class ConcreteEvent extends AbstractEvent<ConcreteAction> { ... }
```

If the command and event action properties need to diverge for some reason, I'd put just those particular properties in the `ConcreteCommand` or `ConcreteEvent` classes.

The inheritance model here is very simple. You may only rarely need to do anything more than extend the abstract classes with nothing more to implement than the common `Action`. And in the case where there are no properties needed for the `Action`, just define a `class EmptyAction implements Action` implementation to use in those types of commands and events.